# Comparing two dataframes and printing specific rows in matching values for a single column

Tags: r

I'm completely new to R and would appreciate some help with this!  I'm trying to compare two large dataframes (first few lines only):

```
d1

LOC.ID
LOC_O1
LOC_O34
LOC_O36
LOC_O78
LOC_O234
LOC_O235
LOC_O2353.1
```

...

```
d2

locus.V.6   V6..model   start   end
LOC_O1      LOC_O1.1    1903    9817
LOC_O234    LOC_O234.1  1903    9817
LOC_O24     LOC_O24.2   10218   11435
LOC_O459    LOC_O459.1  11648   14915
LOC_O34     LOC_O34.2   15292   19323
LOC_O44     LOC_O44.1   15292   1932
```

Anyhow, I'd like to compare the values in the 1st column of d1 with those in the 1st and 2nd column of d2, then if there is a match in either the 1st or 2nd column of d2, print all d2 data in that row.

I don't know how to use if...then statements or loops yet, or this should be relatively simple.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. You are not an idiot. Just take the time to learn how to format your question.

Comment: How do you propose matching on the second column? Are you only matching everying before the `.`?

Comment: Is the second column of `d2` (`V6..model`) always just the first column (`locus.V.6`) with just a `.N` after it? If so, a simple merge like: `merge(d1,d2,by.x="LOC.ID",by.y="locus.V.6",all.x=TRUE)` might work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `data.tables` with `keys`.

> It offers fast subset, fast grouping, fast update, fast ordered joins and list columns in a short and flexible syntax, for faster development. It is inspired by A[B] syntax in R where A is a matrix and B is a 2-column matrix

Assuming that you want to match the `LOC.ID` and `locus.V.6` columns

```
library(data.table)
d1 <- data.table(d1, key = 'LOC.ID')
d2 <- data.table(d2, key = 'locus.V.6')
# nomatch = 0 means non-matches will not be returned
# mult = 'first' or 'last' may also be useful, if you only want these
d2[d1, nomatch=0]

   locus.V.6  V6..model start   end
1:    LOC_O1   LOC_O1.1  1903  9817
2:  LOC_O234 LOC_O234.1  1903  9817
3:   LOC_O34  LOC_O34.2 15292 19323


# the default value for `nomatch` is NA (just like when you use the function match)
# this now has NA values for non-matching rows
d2[d1] 
     locus.V.6  V6..model start   end
1:      LOC_O1   LOC_O1.1  1903  9817
2:    LOC_O234 LOC_O234.1  1903  9817
3:    LOC_O235         NA    NA    NA
4: LOC_O2353.1         NA    NA    NA
5:     LOC_O34  LOC_O34.2 15292 19323
6:     LOC_O36         NA    NA    NA
7:     LOC_O78         NA    NA    NA
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
match <- d2[,1] %in% d1[,1] | d2[,2] %in% d1[,1]
d2[index,]
```

`d1[,x]` is the `x`-th column of dataframe `d1`. `x%in%y` checks which elements in `x` are also in `y`. So first we check which rows in `d1[,1]` are in either `d2[,1]` or in `d2[,2]`, and then show those.