# How to match two time columns and print value if they match?

Tags: r, datetime, match, data.table, aggregate

I am running my head against the wall here. Hope someone can help.

I have an aggregated data frame (d1) in R with a time column and a column with binary values. The time column does not have a uniform time step.

d1:

```
                   Time Set
 1: 2015-01-03 14:55:00   0
 2: 2015-01-06 14:20:00   1
 3: 2015-01-06 14:25:00   1
 4: 2015-01-06 14:30:00   1
 5: 2015-01-06 14:35:00   1
 6: 2015-01-06 14:40:00   1
 7: 2015-01-06 14:45:00   0
 8: 2015-01-06 16:10:00   1
 9: 2015-01-07 07:45:00   0
10: 2015-01-07 08:00:00   1
11: 2015-01-07 08:05:00   1
12: 2015-01-07 08:45:00   0
```

I also have a data frame (d2) with a column with uniform time steps, and the number of rows in d2 is therefore longer than in d1

d2:

```
             Time_Ideal 
 1: 2015-01-09 14:05:00   
 2: 2015-01-09 14:10:00 
 3: 2015-01-09 14:15:00 
 4: 2015-01-09 14:20:00 
 5: 2015-01-09 14:25:00 
 6: 2015-01-09 14:30:00 
 7: 2015-01-09 14:35:00 
 8: 2015-01-09 14:40:00 
 9: 2015-01-09 14:45:00 
10: 2015-01-09 14:50:00
```

What I want to do is to print the Set-value next to the Time_Ideal, where the time values in the two time-columns, in d1 and d2 respectively matches.

I tried

```
d1 <- data.table(d1, key = 'Time')
d2 <- data.table(d2, key = 'Time_Ideal')

d2[d1, nomatch=0]
d2[d1]
```

with inspiration from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15625511/comparing-two-dataframes-and-printing-specific-rows-in-matching-values-for-a-sin)

but I can't make it work properly..

Comment: When there is no Set-value for a given time, I would like to print the value of the Set from the row above..

Comment: Use `dput` to provide data, it will be much easier to reproduce. Also exact expected output would be nice. What I understood from your question is that you get a different column name than you'd expected.

Comment: There isn't a single time stamp that matches between the two files provided, can you show your desired result please? It should be as simple as `setkey(setDT(d1), Time) ; d1[d2]`

Comment: I tested my answer with 3 day shift of d1$Time (see the "Test" section)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the `data.table` way of solving this (as this was the actual question). Using the modified data provided by @bergant (because OP data sets don't match), simply do:

```
setkey(setDT(d1), Time) # `d2` doesn't have to be a `data.table`
d1[d2] # you can set `, nomatch = 0L` if you want to remove non-matches
#                    Time Set
#  1: 2015-01-09 15:05:00  NA
#  2: 2015-01-09 15:10:00  NA
#  3: 2015-01-09 15:15:00  NA
#  4: 2015-01-09 15:20:00   1
#  5: 2015-01-09 15:25:00   1
#  6: 2015-01-09 15:30:00   1
#  7: 2015-01-09 15:35:00   1
#  8: 2015-01-09 15:40:00   1
#  9: 2015-01-09 15:45:00   0
# 10: 2015-01-09 15:50:00  NA
```

---

Another way (better) would be modifying `d2` by reference. You will have to convert `d2` to `data.table` and `key` it first

```
setkey(setDT(d2), Time_Ideal)
d2[d1, Set := i.Set][] # `d2` was modified by reference.
#                    Time Set
#  1: 2015-01-09 15:05:00  NA
#  2: 2015-01-09 15:10:00  NA
#  3: 2015-01-09 15:15:00  NA
#  4: 2015-01-09 15:20:00   1
#  5: 2015-01-09 15:25:00   1
#  6: 2015-01-09 15:30:00   1
#  7: 2015-01-09 15:35:00   1
#  8: 2015-01-09 15:40:00   1
#  9: 2015-01-09 15:45:00   0
# 10: 2015-01-09 15:50:00  NA
```

Comment: Thanks! The first example worked. The (better) did not unfortunately.
But now I just need to replace NA-values with the value above...

Comment: What exactly didn't work? What error did you get? Also, what do you mean by "*replace by value above*"?

Comment: I mean: 
In row 9 above there is a 0. 
In row 10 there is a NA. 
I want the NA to become 0 (equal to value in row 9=the value above). 
etc..
Does it make sense?
I am experimenting with for.loop and if sentences at the moment, but did not make it work yet.

Comment: The error message I get is:
"In `[.data.table`(d2, d1, `:=`(Set, i.Set)) :  Coerced 'double' RHS to 'integer' to match the column's type; may have truncated precision. Either change the target column to 'double' first (by creating a new 'double' vector length 9233 (nrows of entire table) and assign that; i.e. 'replace' column), or coerce RHS to 'integer' (e.g. 1L, NA_[real|integer]_, as.*, etc) to make your intent clear and for speed. Or, set the column type correctly up front when you create the table and stick to it, please."

It is okay. Your first suggestion is perfect

Comment: The error means that you already have `Set` column in `d2`. You shouldn't have it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe with dplyr?

```
library(dplyr)

d2 %>%
  left_join(d1, by = c("Time_Ideal" = "Time"))
```

To fill last value for Set, use:

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

d2 %>%
  left_join(d1, by = c("Time_Ideal" = "Time")) %>%
  mutate(Set = na.locf(d3$Set, na.rm = FALSE))
```

### Test:

#### Input data

There is no hint of the used datetime type. I'm using POSIXct below:

```
d1 <- 
  structure(list(Time = structure(c(1420293300, 1420550400, 1420550700, 
  1420551000, 1420551300, 1420551600, 1420551900, 1420557000, 1420613100, 
  1420614000, 1420614300, 1420616700), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
  ), tzone = ""), 
  Set = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
  1L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), .Names = c("Time", "Set"), 
  class = "data.frame")

d2 <- 
  structure(list(Time_Ideal = structure(c(1420808700, 1420809000, 
  1420809300, 1420809600, 1420809900, 1420810200, 1420810500, 1420810800, 
  1420811100, 1420811400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
  ), tzone = "")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), .Names = "Time_Ideal", 
  class = "data.frame")
```

#### Execute join #1

There is no date intersection (d1 times are < d2 times), so we get NAs:

```
d2 %>%
  left_join(d1, by = c("Time_Ideal" = "Time"))

                Time_Ideal Set
    1  2015-01-09 14:05:00  NA
    2  2015-01-09 14:10:00  NA
    3  2015-01-09 14:15:00  NA
    4  2015-01-09 14:20:00  NA
    5  2015-01-09 14:25:00  NA
    6  2015-01-09 14:30:00  NA
    7  2015-01-09 14:35:00  NA
    8  2015-01-09 14:40:00  NA
    9  2015-01-09 14:45:00  NA
    10 2015-01-09 14:50:00  NA
```

#### Execute join #2 (corrected input data)

Shift d1 for 3 days in the future:

```
d1$Time <- d1$Time + 3600*24*3 # three days shift
```

Execute again

```
d2 %>%
  left_join(d1, by = c("Time_Ideal" = "Time"))

                Time_Ideal Set
    1  2015-01-09 14:05:00  NA
    2  2015-01-09 14:10:00  NA
    3  2015-01-09 14:15:00  NA
    4  2015-01-09 14:20:00   1
    5  2015-01-09 14:25:00   1
    6  2015-01-09 14:30:00   1
    7  2015-01-09 14:35:00   1
    8  2015-01-09 14:40:00   1
    9  2015-01-09 14:45:00   0
    10 2015-01-09 14:50:00  NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best solution but I think it works:

```
library(plyr)

d3 <- d2
colnames(d3) <- c("Time")

d4 <- join(d3, d1)

for(i in 2:length(d4$Set)){
  if(is.na(d4$Set[i])){
    d4$Set[i] <- d4$Set[i - 1]
  } 
}
```